# joomla 3 , adding script to override a module

Tags: jquery, joomla

i am trying to add a line of script to the module which is a simple Q&A accordion in joomla . 
this is the script :

```
        jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".ui-accordion-content-active").attr("tabindex","0");
          });
```

so I went to templates--> create override --> clicked on this accordion module .

then I have created a new file (try.js) inside this override .and clicked save .
but I still cant see, that the website is loading this script ("view page source")

Answer (score 0):

Check the offical documentation

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page